# python file run error, No module name AlchemyAPI

Tags: python, pycharm, alchemyapi

I'm trying to run a Python file called "keywords".  However, in `pycharm`, the `Import AlchemyAPI` is in red error.  I have added the API key to the text file and have renamed the module `AlchempyAPI` (as before it had "-2.5" attached to the name).

I still get the error:

```
No Module Named AlchemyAPI.
```

What can I do next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AlchemyAPI recently released a new Python SDK that is easier to use and will likely solve your issue. You can find it on [GitHub](https://github.com/AlchemyAPI/alchemyapi_python).